# Is "had" necessary in this sentence?

Tags: past-vs-past-perfect

> You failed 9 subjects before you graduated from college.

I read up that its necessary for this to become "you had failed" since there are 2 past tense verbs, and because the "had" gives context that failing the 9 subjects happened before graduating.

But!! I can already completely understand the sentence without the necessary "had". I don't see any other interpretation other than "failed 9 subjects" happens before "you graduated", as that is a logical flow of events, and because there is already a "before".

Comment: No, you don't have to use the past perfect. It all depends on context.

Comment: ahh, alright thanks, I understand, but can I ask what context would require the had to be necessary?

Comment: You would use *had* to discuss a series of events in the past, and to emphasize that this one came first. That would place it in the past perfect tense. It can also sound a bit more formal.